# Copy data from 6 workbooks with matching columns to a single workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have 6 different workbooks with a minimum of 3 sheets in each of them. I want a VBA code to automatically generate the master workbook with the matching columns from the othes.

Workbook 1 - "Baseline"

```
        hstname Loc  Dept   User    logID   HstIP   MACAddr     OS
         abcghj jay  aa     abc     1        2       1.2.3.      7
         sgtsx  jay  ss     sgt     2        3       4.56.8      8
          wrgyr jay  dd     wrg     3        4       5.6.7       8
         dfhbnj jay  tt    gdxvg    4        8      3.4.5.6.7    7
```

Workbook 2 - "Daily1"

```
           hstname    OnlineStatus     result
          abcghj         scan            yes
          sgtsx         scan             yes
          wrgyr         scan             yes
         dfhbnj,         scan            yes
           sdrgswdeg    scan             no
          fhawrtu65      scan            no
```

Workbook 2-"Daily2"

```
         hstname        OnlineStatus      result
          abcghj          scan             yes
           sgtsx          scan            yes
             wrgyr        scan            yes
             dfhbnj,      scan            yes
            sdrgswdeg     scan             no
```

And workboook daily3,daily4, daily5 will have same columns as daily1&daily2.

I have filled out the master sheet as an example for you to understand what exactly is my requirement.
NOTE THAT: in my master sheet the columns ID, hstname,user, dept,loc,mac addr is taken from the "baseline" workbook. If the hstname column matches in "baseline" and in "daily1" workbook then copy the "result" column of daily1 workbook to "daily1" column of Master workbook. Repeat the same for daily2,3,4&5. Also note that there should not be any duplicate values (duplicate hstnames in Master).

MASTER sheet

```
 ID hstname   daily1    daily2  daily3 d4 d5 User     Dept    Loc   MACAddr
  1 abcghj    yes       yes      yes          abc     aa      jay    1.2.3.
  2 sgtsx     notscan   no        no          sgt     ss      jay    4.56.8
  6 wrgyr      yes      yes       no          wrg     dd      jay    5.6.7
  4 dfhbnj,    yes    notscan     no         gdxvg    tt      jay    3.4.5.6.7
  8 24dvg5t    no       yes       yes            xb   ff      jay    9.8.56
```

Tried using this code. but it doesnt serve te purpose completely.

```
   Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
   Dim MyFile As String
   Dim erow
   Dim Filepath As String
   Filepath = "D:\examp\"
   MyFile = Dir(Filepath)
   Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        If MyFile = "master.xlsx" Then
        Exit Sub
        End If

   Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
   Range("A2:D2").Copy
   ActiveWorkbook.Close

   erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))

   MyFile = Dir
    Loop
    End Sub
```

Comment: hello Apurva, Stackoverflow is not a request code service I'm afraid.  Maybe show us how you would try to do it in another programming language that you know.

Comment: Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
            Dim MyFile As String
            Dim erow
          Dim Filepath As String
          Filepath = "D:\examp\"
          MyFile = Dir(Filepath)
        Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
         If MyFile = "master.xlsx" Then
       Exit Sub
       End If
    
    Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
   Range("A2:D2").Copy
  ActiveWorkbook.Close
    
       erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))
       MyFile = Dir 
      Loop
     End Sub

Comment: Please edit your question with this info

Comment: ya done. i have attached a piece of code which serves the purpose just 1%.

Answer (score 1):

If you have never used VBA before you could try turning on the macro recorder and discovering what the functions do. Honestly this is how most of us got started using VBA. Some great sites to learn from are Ozgrid or Mr. Excel. Some code for us to inspect would be very helpful in getting you in the right direction.